# GPS co-ordinate search --R-trees

Tags: python, gps

I have a list of lists in the form of

[ [ x1,.....,x8],[x1,.......,x8],...............,[x1,.....x[8]] ] . The number of lists in that list can go upto a million.   Each list has 4 gps co-ordinates which show the four points of a rectangle ( assumed that each segment is in the form of a rectangle].

Problem : Given a new point, I need to determine which segment the point falls on and create a new one if it falls in none of them. I am not uploading the data into MySQL as of now, it comes in as a simple text file.  I find out the co-ordinates from the text file for any given car.

What I tried : I am thinking of using R-trees to find all points which are near to the given point . ( Near== 200 meters maximum) . But even in R-trees, there seem to be too many options . R,R*,Hilbert.

Q1. Which one should be opted for ?

Q2. Is there a better option than R-trees?Can something be done by searching faster within the list ?

Thanks a lot.

[ {a1:[........]},{a2:[.......]},{a3:[.........]},.... ,{a20:[.....]}]  .

Comment: Would it be possible to calculated the segment reference at the point of saving the coordinates? Then I would probably use just a dictionary with the key being the segment and then check something like "if mydict.get(region): listofcoordinates.append(newones) else mydict[region]=[newcoordinates]" if the region was already there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't the problem *"find whether a given point falls within a certain rectangle in 2D space"*?

That could be separated dimensionally, couldn't it? Give each rectangle an ID, then separate into lists of one-dimensional ranges (`(id, x0, x1)`, `(id, y0, y1)`) and find all the ranges in both dimensions the point falls in. (I'm fairly sure there are very efficient algorithms for this. Heck, you could even leverage, say, sqlite already.) Then just intersect the ID sets you get and you should find all rectangles the point falls in, if any. (Of course you can exit early if either of the single dimensional queries returns no result.)

Not sure if this'd be faster or smarter than R-trees or [other spatial indexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spatial_index) though. Hope this helps anyway.

Comment: Thanks.  I haven't yet thought about leveraging existing Db methods actually :( . I should probably give it more serious thought

Comment: I am thinking that if i use DB , will it be scalable ?  And there will be single point of failure right ? How about if I use lucene ? Will that help instead ? I guess with B and B+-trees, it won't be scalable. Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: Depends on the database, I suppose. Also, MySQL already supports some GIS methods (though, if I remember correctly, only on MyISAM tables -- not sure if that's a problem with your deployment.)

Comment: Also, I just realized there's http://gis.stackexchange.com/ -- you may want to ask there too!

Comment: I actually did ask there first :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
import random as ra

# my _data will hold tuples of gps readings
# under the key of (row,col), knowing that the size of 
# the row and col is 10, it will give an overall grid coverage.
# Another dict could translate row/col coordinates into some 
# more usefull region names

my_data = {}


def get_region(x,y,region_size=10):
    """Build a tuple of row/col based on
       the values provided and region square dimension.
       It's for demonstration only and it uses rather naive calculation as
       coordinate / grid cell size"""
    row = int(x / region_size)
    col = int(y / region_size)
    return (row,col)


#make some examples and build my_data
for loop in range(10000):
    #simule some readings
    x = ra.choice(range(100))
    y = ra.choice(range(100))
    my_coord = get_region(x,y)
    if my_data.get(my_coord):
        my_data[my_coord].append((x,y))
    else:
        my_data[my_coord]= [(x,y),]

print my_data
```

Comment: How does this answer any of the questions OP has asked?

Comment: It presents a different approach to work of the grid instead of trying to work out the relation of the current reading to all the previous ones, but I think it might solve the underlying problem. Maybe not, we shall see.

Comment: I found the min and max longitude, and divided into 20 intervals and am just storing the intervals in the dictionary like mentioned somewhere.  I would love an answer to the R-trees part coz they still look like the better option, especially with too many segments ( i will really have too many)

Comment: I am curious about R-trees myself, with the grid though you would not need to traverse all the segments anyway as you would already know what the neighbours are. E.g. current one is (10,10) so you limit the list of segments immediately to (9,9), (9,10), (9,11), (...) (11,11). Using these as keys, you could get all the neighbour locations.

Comment: Let me try this and get back to you .  :)  As this goes directly into deployment, I am being a little extra careful to ensure things work as expected